# linq group & sum query

Tags: linq

I have an Entity Framework object which represents a telephone call.

How can I group the dialed numbers by duration
and project that into { Number = xxx, DurationSum = yyy }

I'm a linq newbie and can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Please show your code so far as well as the entities used. Furthermore, you should be able to solve this yourself with the answer to your last question...

Comment: Hi Trevor, can you give us some more information please?  What does the schema of your telephone call object look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
var query = from call in db.Calls
            group call by call.Number into g
            select new { Number = g.Key, DurationSum = g.Sum(c => c.Duration) };
```

Comment: Thanks, I was overcomplicating it

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a class like this

```
class DialedNumber {
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
}
```

And you have a collection named dialedNumbers. You can use a query like this

```
var groupResult = from dialNumber in dialNumbers
                  group dialNumber by dialNumber.Number
                  into dialNumberGroup
                  select new { 
                               Number = dialNumberGroup.Key, 
                               DurationSum = dialNumberGroup.Sum(d => d.Duration) 
                             };
```

I haven't tested it yet. I hope this will answer your question.